# Couchbase for mobile app

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I have an app using endpoint that are running in docker containers, 
that again serves data from cassandra.

I have created Facebook authentication on the backend and would like to have more like Google etc.

Question: Does Couchbase have authentication for Facebook and otheres?
I am thinking, that if so, I could remove all docker containers for endpoints and authentication, and just use Couchbase as backend for mobile apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase Mobile does support authentication for Facebook and other identity providers.

From [Couchbase Mobile - Guides - Authentication](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/authentication/index.html)

> - OpenID Connect Authentication: use OpenID Connect providers (Google+, Paypal, etc.) to authenticate users.
> - Static providers: Sync Gateway currently supports authentication endpoints for Facebook, Google+ and OpenID Connect providers

And this tutorial will help with the approach you have in mind:
[Couchbase Mobile - Tutorial](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/training/index.html)